# Python xhtml2pdf to generate PDF in landscape mode

Tags: python, django, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

I am using the python xhtml2pdf module and the pisa class to create a PDF. Now the PDF is in vertical A4 format, how do I change it to have the PDF to landscape layout?

```
import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa
result = StringIO()
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
        StringIO("This is my PDF"),
        result)
```

Answer (score 16):

Use the following CSS:

```
@page {
    size: letter landscape;
    margin: 2cm;
}
```